# Ruby on rails 4.0 + javascript not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a javascript file called "front.js" i load from "application.js" like usual with this code:

```
//= require front
```

Inside "front.js",i have many functions i want to launch when the document is ready like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#test").click(function(event){
    ...
  });
});
```

But the problem is "front.js" is loaded only when i refresh the page manually (ctrl+r / f5 ) and not when i move from page to page, so my javascript code cannot be executed as wanted. Maybe this comes from turbolinks, i dont know how to handle this issue. When i put scripts directly in the html files, it works but it's definitely not the right thing to do.

Can anyone help me on this please ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 4: how to use $(document).ready() with turbo-links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links)

Comment: Actually i didn't know if this problem came from Turbolinks or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three ways by which you can do it.

a. You can wrap your jquery code inside a function and then call that function on page load. If your function is ready then you can do:

```
$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

b. You can use jquery's live event or "on" event:

```
$(document).on("click","#test",function(){
 // your code
});
```

c. You can use the jquery-turbolinks gem which will bind the Rails Turbolink events to the document.ready events so you can write your jQuery in the usual way. For more information refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links)

Answer (score 2):

It's due to turbolinks, do this instead

```
var ready;
ready = function() {
  $("#test").click(function(event){
    ...
  });
};
$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when using foundation in my project, you can disable turoblinks by not requiring turbolinks in your application.js file and it should solve the problem.

Comment: Also be sure to take out references to turbolinks in places like application.html.erb.  Do a recursive grep search on your project to be sure you rip out all traces of of that "feature," and your JS may start working normally.